# curl -k or --insecure equivalent to Powershell Invoke-WebRequest not working

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to execute:

```
$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -Body $postParams;
```

And I am always getting 403 forbidden, in ubuntu or git terminal this works like a charm (with -k or --insecure):

```
curl -k -X POST "https://MYURL" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"user\" : \"myUser\", \"password\" : \"myPass\"}"
```

or

```
curl -X POST "https://MYURL" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"user\" : \"myUser\", \"password\" : \"myPass\"}" --insecure
```

After some research I tried two solutions:

Solution #1:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true };

$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -Body $postParams;
```

Did not work still getting 403 forbidden.

Solution #2:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true };

$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -Body $postParams;

add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy;

$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -Body $postParams;
```

Did not work either, still getting 403 forbidden.

Any clues of what I might be doing wrong? Since it works ok in ubuntu and git terminal with `-k` or `--insecure`.

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem - `-k`/`--insecure` affect TLS handshakes, not the inner HTTP stream. The likeliest explanation is that PowerShell formats your parameter values in a way that the web server doesn't recognize. Try passing the same payload as a raw string: `-Body '{"user":"myUser","pass":"myPass"}'`

Comment: first of all, thank your answer!

Did you mean?
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -Body '{user='myUser';password='myPass'}';

Still getting 403 forbidden, and the curl in linux still working...

Comment: You are missing `-ContentType 'application/json'`, try to add it and see if it will work. Might forbid other types of requests. Note, there is also `Invoke-RestMethod` which might work better for your use case.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $postParams;` and `$postParams = @{user='myUser';password='myPass'};
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://MYURL -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $postParams;`.. but still getting 403

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, is `Invoke-WebRequest` is not an attempt to replace `curl` and simply does not support this feature.

So far, the only way I found without using other PS modules is something that should never be done (credit goes to: [ref](https://til.intrepidintegration.com/powershell/ssl-cert-bypass))

Run this before running the `Invoke-WebRequest` command. It may popup an internet explorer lock warning, but still lets the PS command run, ignoring an expired cert.

```
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPol
```